# What is the difference between intArrayOf() and arrayOf()?

Tags: kotlin

In some sources I read that the first creates an array of elements of primitive type Int, and the second of packed Integer, in others that in Kotlin there are no primitive types, and it is the same. I haven't found any consensus, I'd be grateful if someone could explain.

Googled and read the book Kotlin in Actions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arrayOf` produce an object of class `Array<T>`. As you initialize array using this function, primitive values that you provide as arguments are being *boxed*. In other words, primitive integer value `1` will be converted to the object of type `Int` with value `1`.

```
val array = arrayOf(1, 2, 3) // array's type is Array<Int>
```

`intArrayOf` is a function to create object of type `IntArray`. This class does not have boxing overhead. Therefore values that you provide are not being boxed.

```
val array = intArrayOf(1, 2, 3) // array's type is IntArray
```

Note that both classes `IntArray` and `Array<T>` have no inheritance relation. But they contain same set of methods and properties.

`IntArray` represents primitive type arrays, which are designed specifically to prevent deriving array type from provided elements and avoid boxing overhead.

However, if you are calling `get` method on `IntArray`, you will get value of type `Int`, same as when you call get on `Array<Int>`.